# Can somebody list all the tools in this photo

Tags: arduino, tools, drone

Can somebody list all the tools on this image? I'm building my lab and I ill need a list of must-have electronic instruments. My goal is to 3d print parts and builds drones. Drone recharging stations and other custom stuff.

[image]

Comment: If you're building your lab to do a particular task, why are you asking about a random lab which could be producing anything?

Comment: "My goal is to 3d print parts and builds drones" - Well you'll need a 3D printer, hope that helps

Comment: bottles of water, must stay hydrated.

Answer (score 4):

If you're planning on setting up a personal lab, Generally you will be needing:

- Bread Boards
- Jumper Cables, Patch cords (Preferably with Alligator clips)
- Digital Multimeter (An electronics engineer's stethoscope)
- Lab Bench Power Supply (This is what you use to generally power up your electronic circuits for testing and so on)
- Digital Oscilloscope (Preferably from Keysight, based on personal experience)
- Signal Generators (This is where you can experiment with waves like Sine, Triangle, Square, Saw tooth and so on)
- A generic electronics active/passive components within a utility box (This is where you house your Resistors, Capacitors, Inductors, Transistors and so on with color code so its easy to navigate to while building your circuitry)
- Soldering Station (A good investment on a soldering equipment can last you a lifetime of tinkering)
- Glue guns and other adhesives
- Clamp kit (It can hold your components or PCB in position if you intend to do micro soldering and so on)

These are whats on your picture. Personally, these are more than sufficient for you to start working on your daily projects be it drones or not. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what [Nomad wrote](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/519774/65584). It of course heavily depends on what you are doing, and how much budget you have.

Other items which have become invaluable for me:

- Logic analyzer (personal recommendation: Saleae)
- USB to serial converters, in the end plain old TTL UART works very well for a lot of things
- Professional level development tools, it's a PITA when the tools you are using provide several pitfalls just because they are not up to the task (like they cannot resolve references while stepping through the code and everything is suddenly a null pointer)
- at least a second multimeter

If your budget is constraint I'd probably drop the signal generator for the logic analyzer. But then I spend a lot more time on embedded software than on hardware, so the priorities are certainly different.

Comment: Best bit of budget kit I bought was the 'Digilent - Analog Discovery 2'. Might not have the greatest specs but for the price you can get a handful of average instruments in one